# Left join to filter rows on UPDATE?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to update a table but I need to do a left join to determine which rows I want to select.

These are two examples of what I've been trying, I think it's clear what I want to do by seeing any of them:

```
   UPDATE `User_Likes` 
      SET `Status` = 'read'
LEFT JOIN Posts ON User_Likes.PID = Posts.ID
    WHERE Posts.UID = '1'
```

Here I'm trying another way:

```
UPDATE `User_Likes` 
   SET `Status` = 'read' 
 WHERE `ID` IN (SELECT Posts.ID
                  FROM `User_Likes`
             LEFT JOIN Posts ON User_Likes.PID = Posts.ID
                 WHERE Posts.UID = '$userID')
```

Comment: Can you provide more information about what is wrong - sample data, before and after.  To see what your desired result is.

Comment: Yes, I want to update field Status to Read, but I need to do the join to determine who is the author of the post that has been liked. (I only have the Post ID in User_Likes). First query returns: `You have an error in your SQL syntax (no more info provided)` Second query returns: `You can't specify target table 'User_Likes' for update in FROM clause`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this Example

```
UPDATE User_Likes
LEFT JOIN
Posts ON User_Likes.PID = Posts.ID 
SET Status='read'
WHERE Posts.UID = '1' ;
```

### [SQL Fiddle DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/38a399/1/0)

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your query is that Id expects only one Id, and your select statement returns multiple ID.
so:

```
UPDATE `User_Likes` 
   SET `Status` = 'read'
FROM `User_Likes`
LEFT JOIN Posts ON User_Likes.PID = Posts.ID
WHERE Posts.UID = '$userID'
```

Some thing like this..

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE `User_Likes` u LEFT JOIN Posts p 
ON u.User_Likes.PID = p.Posts.ID
SET `Status` = 'read'
WHERE p.Posts.UID = '1'
```